# Kafka logs in go service

Tags: go, logging, apache-kafka

I need kafka consumer logs for debug. I do the following:

```golang
    chanLogs := make(chan confluentkafka.LogEvent)
    go func() {
        for {
            logEv := <-chanLogs
            logger.Debug("KAFKA: " + logEv.String())
        }
    }()

    configMap["go.logs.channel.enable"] = true
    configMap["go.logs.channel"] = chanLogs

    consumer, err := confluentkafka.NewConsumer(&configMap)

    err := consumer.SubscribeTopics(Topics, nil)
```

And I never get a line. I tried it with kafka chan (`consumer.Logs()`) with the same result. What I do wrong?

**UPD**
In initial post I wrongfully set parameter name. The correct one is `go.logs.channel.enable`. But sometimes this still don't work.

Comment: try adding `go.logs.channel.enable` equal `true` to the configmap

Answer (score 3):

The solution was to add

```golang
    configMap["debug"] = "all"
```

I found it [here](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/blob/194896a278506e9ac36e48d54abd123f0dcb3800/kafka/consumer_test.go#L372)

Answer (score 2):

As described in the doc, you should enable that feature:

```
go.logs.channel.enable (bool, false) - Forward log to Logs() channel.
go.logs.channel (chan kafka.LogEvent, nil) - Forward logs to application-provided channel instead of Logs(). Requires go.logs.channel.enable=true.
```

So change your code like:

```
    configMap["go.logs.channel"] = chanLogs
    configMap["go.logs.channel.enable"] = true

    consumer, err := confluentkafka.NewConsumer(&configMap)
```

See also in the [doc](https://docs.confluent.io/5.5.0/clients/confluent-kafka-go/index.html#NewConsumer) or in the sample on the code repo [here](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/blob/master/examples/transactions_example/generator.go#L80)

Comment: Yes, I erroneously wrote bad key name. But it does't work with the right one too. The  solution is the parameter `debug` as [here](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/blob/194896a278506e9ac36e48d54abd123f0dcb3800/kafka/consumer_test.go#L372)

Comment: why is it "go.logs.channel" not just "go.logs"? what is .channel telling us?